# Position last HTML element at top of page

Tags: css, html, css-position

I have layout kind of like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="body"></div>
  <div id="header"></div>
</body>
```

What I want to do is have #header with a variable height positioned at the top of the page with absolute top:0, and have #body displayed below #header without being layered underneath.

Important:

- #header must be below #body in the markup
- #header must be displayed as if it were above #body in the markup
- #header has a dynamically variable height, so I cannot assign #body a fixed top padding
- I cannot use Javascript at all, it must only be HTML and CSS

Comment: okay, but why in the world is your header under the body tag? i guess we deserve a little bit education on what you're planning.

Comment: are you talking about fixed position ?? if not no need of absolute positioning just have header before body that should do it

Comment: Why are you asking us to do your homework?

Comment: @Viscocent Let's hope it isn't "for SEO reasons"; I've seen enough of this urban legend... OP: as long as #header has variable height (and it has: zooming, changing default font-size, etc etc), there's NO sure way of doing that

Comment: Oops I'm wrong. [flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) can do that easily, except it's IE10+ (there's also a nasty hack of `display: table-something` I'm not proud of... ^^)

Comment: It is for html email actually, not homework or SEO. I have an interactive HTML/CSS bar at the top of the email with the contents of the email below it. The problem is that message previews show the first content within the markup, which in this case is content in the top bar. Ideal behaviour would be for email previews to display the actual contents.

In the example above, #header would be the top bar and #body would be the email contents.

This is the only arrangement I can think of where the email content in #body would be displayed first.

Comment: @FelipeAls - I was not aware of flexbox before! This is going to work well for us since we're focused towards mobile email. After implementing flexbox my message previews successfully display the email contents while keeping my bar at the top of the email. Thanks :) If you reply with an answer I'll mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code which will set the absolute top position to 0:

```
#header {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
}
```

also I would recommend using the new HTML5 `<header>` tag instead of `<div id="header"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

In the answer of "dsdev" the header would not get a variable height.

`<div id="body">BODY</div>
 <div id="header">
    HEADER
    <br />
    HEADER
    <br />
    HEADER
 </div>`

http://jsfiddle.net/uQ2RE/

I think there is no way using html and css only because the only way to position #header above #body is by using the css ´position´ element and that leads to no variable height.